# Returning a string from a Ruby function

Tags: ruby

In this example:

```
def hello
  puts "hi"
end

def hello
  "hi"
end
```

What's the difference between the first and second functions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Ruby functions, when a return value is **not** *explicitly* defined, *a function will return the **last statement it evaluates***. If *only* a `print` statement is evaluated, the function will return `nil`.

Thus, the following *prints* the string `hi` and *returns* `nil`:

```
puts "hi"
```

In contrast, the following *returns* the string `hi`:

```
"hi"
```

Consider the following:

```
def print_string
  print "bar"
end

def return_string
  "qux" # same as `return "qux"`
end

foo = print_string
foo #=> nil

baz = return_string
baz #=> "qux"
```

Note, however, that you can `print` and `return` something out of the same function:

```
def return_and_print
  print "printing"
  "returning" # Same as `return "returning"`
end
```

The above will `print` the string `printing`, but return the string `returning`.

Remember that you can always **explicitly define a return value**:

```
def hello
  print "Someone says hello" # Printed, but not returned
  "Hi there!"                # Evaluated, but not returned
  return "Goodbye"           # Explicitly returned
  "Go away"                  # Not evaluated since function has already returned and exited
end

hello
#=> "Goodbye"
```

So, in sum, if you want to *print* something out of a function, say, to the console/log – use `print`. If you want to *return* that thing out of the function, *don't* just `print` it – ensure that it is returned, either explicitly or by default.

Comment: Good stuff.  Very thorough.  @zeantsoi

Answer (score 1):

The first one uses the `puts` method to write "hi" out to the console and returns `nil`

the second one returns the string "hi" and doesn't print it

Here's an example in an irb session:

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > def hello
2.0.0p247 :002?>   puts "hi"
2.0.0p247 :003?> end
 => nil 
2.0.0p247 :004 > hello
hi
 => nil 
2.0.0p247 :005 > def hello
2.0.0p247 :006?>   "hi"
2.0.0p247 :007?> end
 => nil 
2.0.0p247 :008 > hello
 => "hi"
2.0.0p247 :009 >
```

Answer (score 0):

puts prints it to the console.
So

```
def world
  puts 'a'
  puts 'b'
  puts 'c'
end
```

Will print 'a' then 'b' then 'c' to the console.

```
def world
  'a'
  'b'
  'c'
end
```

This will return the last thing, so you will only see 'c'