# Difference between print and return

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When inside of a method in Ruby, what is the difference between `print` and `return`?

```
def squared_number(num)
  return (num**2)
end
```

and

```
def squared_number(num)
  print (num**2)
end
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018633/what-is-the-difference-between-print-and-puts

Comment: also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21821074/returning-a-string-from-a-ruby-function

Comment: FYI: Ruby methods return the last line, in that case `return` is not necessary.

Comment: `print` and `return` have entirely different functions in the language. One outputs to the console or a file stream, and the other changes program flow and optionally returns a value. `return` never outputs to the console or a file stream.

Comment: Think of it this way: the `print` method is for telling _humans_ something; the `return` statement is for telling _the rest of the program_ the result of a method call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`return` ends current method returning passed parameter as a result. Example:

```
def add(a, b)
    return a + b
end

c = add(1, 2)
```

In Ruby last statement returns value automatically. So we can define our `add` method like this

```
def add(a, b)
    a + b
end
```

But `return` is very useful, if you want to end a method execution prior to the last line. For example:

```
def specialAdd(a, b)
    if a < 0
        return -1
    end
    a + b
end
```

This method returns always -1 if the first argument is negative. In all other cases it works just like `add` method.

On the other hand the `print` method outputs the passed parameter to the standard output (console) returning `nil` as a result. We can see it using `irb` - interactive ruby console:

```
$ irb
irb(main):002:0> print "Hello World\n"
Hello World
=> nil
irb(main):003:0>
```

Here we see `"Hello World"` plus newline printed. The returned value of the print method is `nil`.

Answer (score 5):

A lot.

`print` will output the number without a newline on the end.

`return` will return the number from the method.